# How to use Basic api token and JWT token both are working in same api in php Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, lumen

Currently my apis are secured using basic authentication token. i would like to use jwt token authentication into my code. But i would like my apis to be secured by both mechanism together. what i do for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use both api and web middleware together

```
Route::middleware("auth:web,api")->group(function () {
///     your apis here
})
```